# Создать цикл в регулярных выражениях

Tags: python-3.x

Необходимо создать цикл, чтобы не вбивать по новой каждый раз новый 'pattern'. Я думаю, нужно как то использовать эти пиксели, так как каждый pattern отличается между собой пикселями (+100 пикселей каждый раз, начиная с 0px и заканчивая 900px). Прошу прощения за плохое объяснение. Новичок в программировании.

```
for i in result:
   r1=re.sub('(?s)<!--(.*?)-->','',i)
   pattern0 = '<div style=position:absolute;left:0px>(.*?)</div>'
   result0 = re.findall(pattern0, r1)[0]
   pattern1 = '<div style=position:absolute;left:100px>(.*?)</div>'
   result1 = re.findall(pattern1, r1)[0]
   ...
   pattern9 = '<div style=position:absolute;left:900px>(.*?)</div>'
   result9 = re.findall(pattern9, r1)[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resultList = []

for i in result:
    r1 = re.sub('(?s)<!--(.*?)-->','', i)

    for j in range(0, 1000, 100):
        pattern = '<div style=position:absolute;left:{}px>(.*?)</div>'.format(j)
        resultList.append(re.findall(pattern, r1)[0])

print(resultList)
```